# Calculate actual total day from starting date to ending date

Tags: php, date

I have some simple question regarding about calculate the actual day from **Starting Date** to **Ending Date**.

Inside the calculation will include leap year, how many day in a month.

Example:

**Starting Date :** 15-03-2014

**Ending Date    :** 11-06-2015

Result: 453 days

I had read one question quite similar with this. But it is not I want. 
[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: I prefer to use the Unix time stamp for all of these issues. The oddities of our calendar system is irrelevant when working with a more or less pure time symbol. Just use `$daysApart = ($date1-$date2)/86400`

Comment: I'm working with some systems relevant with hotel. Therefore, I need to display the day left very accurate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: @Nanne, I had mentioned I read this question and the answer was not what I looking for. Please check the link I attached at my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be using **[`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime)** (and **[`DateInterval`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)**) objects. Convert each date string into a DateTime object and use the `DateTime::diff()` method to calculate the number of days between the two:

```
$dt1 = new DateTime($date1);
$dt2 = new DateTime($date2);
$diff = $dt2->diff($dt1);
echo $diff->format("%a"); // => 453
```

Answer (score 0):

using Jquery you can get actual days

```
var due = due_date_month + '/' + due_date_day + '/' + due_date_year;
var deliver = deliver_date_month + '/' + deliver_date_day + '/' + deliver_date_year;

var deliver_date = new Date(deliver);

var due_date = new Date(due);

if (due_date > deliver_date) {
var difference = Math.floor(due_date - deliver_date);

difference = parseInt(difference / 86400000);
alert(difference);

}
```

Comment: Not every day has 864000 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could to convert the dates to unix time using [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php),
to substract dates, and divide result for 86400 (seconds in a day),
like this:

```
$start = strtotime($date1);
$end = strtotime($date2);
$diff = $end-$start;
$days = ceil($diff/86400); //or floor depends what you need
```

p.s.: $start and $end must be in US format

Comment: Not every day has 864000 seconds (if you take DST into consideration).

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF('ending date','Starting date');

    Ex. 
$q=mysql_query('select DATEDIFF('$end_date','$start_date')' AS total_days <from table name>');
    $result=mysql_fetch_array($q);

    echo $result['total_days'];
```